# R: Compute monthly averages for daily values

Tags: r, average, panel

I have the following data which is stored as a data.frame in R:
[Daily value of product A, B and C from 2018-08-01 until 2019-12-31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXdRC.png)

Now I would like to compute the monthly average of the value for each product. Additionally, only data for the weekdays but not the weekends should be used to calculate the monthly average for each product. What would be the approach in R to get to the required data?

Comment: Please provide the code to create your minimal dataset instead of adding the image. You can use `dput` to do so.

Comment: Like this? structure(list(`ï»¿Product` = c("A", "B", "C"), `Value 2018-08-01` = c(120L, 
100L, 90L), `Value 2018-08-02` = c(80L, 140L, 20L), `Value 2018-08-03` = c(50L, 
70L, 200L), `Value 2018-12-31` = c(50L, 24L, 24L), `Value 2019-01-01` = c(44L, 
60L, 29L), `Value 2019-12-31` = c(99L, 49L, 49L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

Comment: I would use ```tidyr::pivot_longer()``` to put your data in long format, then format the dates so dates becomes of class ```Date```. Afterwhich, you can use ```aggregate()``` or summarise functions from ```dplyr```.  Also for working with data with dates, the ```lubridate``` package might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(Product = c("A", "B", "C"), "Value_2018-08-01" = c(120L, 100L, 90L), 
                     "Value_2018-08-02" = c(80L, 140L, 20L), "Value_2018-08-03" = c(50L, 70L, 200L), 
                     "Value_2018-12-31" = c(50L, 24L, 24L), "Value_2019-01-01" = c(44L, 60L, 29L), 
                     "Value_2019-12-31" = c(99L, 49L, 49L))



df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(c(starts_with("Value"))) %>%
  mutate(Date = name,
         Date = sub(".*_", "", Date),
         Date = as.Date(Date, format="%Y.%m.%d"),
         weekday = weekdays(Date)) %>% 
  filter(!weekday %in% c("Samstag", "Sonntag")) %>% 
  group_by(Product, format(Date, "%m")) %>% 
  summarize(mean(value)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

  Product format(Date, "%m") mean(value)
1       A                 01    44.00000
2       A                 08    83.33333
3       A                 12    74.50000
4       B                 01    60.00000
5       B                 08   103.33333
6       B                 12    36.50000
7       C                 01    29.00000
8       C                 08   103.33333
9       C                 12    36.50000
```

Note that Samstag and Sonntag should be changed to the names of the weekend days in the language of your working system.

Also, I've calculated the monthly averages as you asked for it. However, if you want to have monthly averages per year, you should change `group_by(Product, format(Date, "%m"))`to `group_by(Product, format(Date, "%m"),format(Date, "%Y")`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Really appreciate it.